# How to disable rfkill after it has been uninstalled from Raspbian

Tags: systemd, wifi, raspberry-pi, kernel-modules, raspbian

After performing a system update, I suddenly noticed the Wi-Fi on my Raspberry Pi 4 stopped working. No IP address. So I try obtaining a new lease (simple DHCP configuration) with `dhclient wlan0`, which gets punished by error message `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill`.

After brief Googling, I find [a suggestion to simply purge the package](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=213311) with `apt purge rfkill`, which of course I immediately ran without hesitation. Now I'm left with no userland `rfkill` command or tools, the `rfkill` kernel module continues to reload, preventing me from activating my Wi-Fi (and thus unable to simply reinstall `rfkill` via `apt`), and I cannot figure out how to prevent it from starting.

What I've done:

```bsh
sudo systemctl disable rfkill
sudo systemctl stop rfkill
echo "rfkill" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
sudo mv /lib/systemd/{systemd-rfkill,system/systemd-rfkill.{service,socket}} ~
echo "0" | sudo tee /var/lib/systemd/rfkill/*
```

Inside `/lib/systemd/system/raspberrypi-net-mods.service`, I commented out:

```bsh
#After=systemd-rfkill.service
```

And finally appended `systemd.restore_state=0` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=738a4d67-02 rootfstype=ext4 rootfsflags=commit=120,data=writeback elevator=deadline noatime nodiratime data=writeback fsck.repair=yes rootwait systemd.restore_state=0
```

After rebooting, I can see from `lsmod` that the `rfkill` module is *still* being loaded, and any attempt to run `dhclient wlan0` results in the same original error message!

So how do I disable or remove `rfkill` and re-enable my Wi-Fi adapter?

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Release:        testing
Codename:       bullseye

$ uname -a
Linux jam 4.19.118-v7l+ #1311 SMP Mon Apr 27 14:26:42 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Linux kernel parameter documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) you also need to add the `rfkill.default_state=1` parameter (in addition to `systemd.restore_state=0`) to the kernel `/boot/cmdline.txt` so that it gets set to unblocked as default:

```
    rfkill.default_state=1
```